# What are the consequences of disabling relation generation in the JOOQ generator?

Tags: java, sql, code-generation, jooq

I can disable identity, foreign key, and unique key generation in the JOOQ generator by setting the following [configuration options](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.3/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/):

```
<generate>
  <!-- Primary key / foreign key relations should be generated and used.
       This is a prerequisite for various advanced features.
       Defaults to true -->
  <relations>false</relations>
```

Despite the FK/UK information not being present in the meta-model, what exactly are the consequences of disabling this generation? Which features of JOOQ itself depend upon this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, most of the features documented in the manual's section about CRUD will be unavailable to you:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/

#### Primary keys

Without knowledge about primary keys, there are no [`UpdatableRecord`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html). I.e., you will not be able to write things like:

```
// This works:
MyTableRecord record =
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(MY_TABLE)
   .where(MY_TABLE.ID.eq(1))
   .fetchOne();

// These won't work:
record.store();
record.update();
record.refresh();
record.delete();

// This will still work:
record.insert();
```

#### Foreign keys

Foreign key information is currently used in only a few places in jOOQ, among others, [navigation methods](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/navigation-methods/):

```
BookRecord book = DSL.using(configuration)
                     .selectFrom(BOOK).where(BOOK.ID.eq(1)).fetchOne();

// This won't work
AuthorRecord author = book.fetchParent(FK_BOOK_AUTHOR);
```

There are also plans to enhance the code generator to generate such navigation methods ([#4210](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4210)), which means that the following won't work:

```
// This won't work
AuthorRecord author = book.fetchFkBookAuthor();
```

Or, the synthetic [`JOIN ON KEY`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/join-clause/) clause:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select()
   .from(AUTHOR)
   .join(BOOK).onKey()
   .fetch();
```

There will be other features depending on the availability of constraint information in the future, but ordinary SQL statements aren't affected.